# Is it safe to have a DNS record pointing to an unused AWS ELB instance?

Tags: domain-name-system, security, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Where I work, we have many subdomains of our main domain pointing to ELB instances (with CNAME records) that are no longer in use (like my-loadbalancer-1234567890.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com). I realize this is a bad practice, but our developers seem to have done this a lot.

How dangerous is it that we have these DNS records? Can someone claim these instance names and start serving content on our subdomains?

As far as I know, every ELB instance's name contains 10 random digits that aren't controlled by the user. Is this correct? Can a user influence the generation of these digits in any way?

Answer (score 2):

No one can intentionally claim those names since they are assigned randomly, as you noted. I'd recommend regardless that you consider using [Cloudformation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/), [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/), or another tool to manage creation and cleanup of environments. While the situation you describe probably isn't particularly risky; if DNS records aren't being maintained you have to ask what else isn't.